# This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement. Widget build(BuildContext context)

Tags: flutter

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  const test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/")
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the **return** keyword before InAppWebView

Comment: HI canyou show me how to do that?

Comment: class test extends StatelessWidget {
  const test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    **return** InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/")
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: one last thing sir 

howcan I change the icon in this code

GButton(
                      icon: FlutterIcons.search_fea,
                      text: 'FAQ'.tr(),
                    ),

I want to change the search_fea to a box icon

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).